# Webservices : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a scenario where i have created a web service, which returns the first name and last name of the username passed through client(webservice consumer).

but im getting an error in 5th line :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Below is the code using to retrieve data

```
protected void BindUserDetails(string userName)
    {
        UserService.ServiceSoapClient client = new UserService.ServiceSoapClient();
        DataSet dsresult = new DataSet();
       XmlElement exelement = client.GetUserDetails(userName);
        if (exelement != null)
        {
            XmlNodeReader nodereader = new XmlNodeReader(exelement);
            dsresult.ReadXml(nodereader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
            gvUserDetails.DataSource = dsresult;
            gvUserDetails.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            gvUserDetails.DataSource = null;
            gvUserDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

UserService is the Service reference which i have added.
gvUserDetails is the gridview

```
[WebMethod]
    public XmlElement GetUserDetails(string username) {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestingCS"].ConnectionString);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from userInfo where username=@username", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
        XmlElement xmlElement = xmldata.DocumentElement;
        return xmlElement;



    }
```

thanks

Comment: Well presumably `GetUserDetails` returns an `XElement`, so use LINQ to XML instead. Personally I'd prefer that over using the old DOM API anyway :)

Comment: What does the proxy code look like? If the *client-side* `GetUserDetails` method returns `XmlElement`, then your original compilation error makes no sense.

Comment: (Also, you should use a `using` statement in your web method...)

Comment: thats the only code im using ..  i don't have any additional code in my prog

Comment: Well you do - you've got the generated proxy code for the service. That's why I asked what return type was shown if you hover over the method name in the client code. What *does* get shown?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Well the error message seems reasonably clear - `GetUserDetails` is returning `XElement` (from LINQ to XML) rather than `XmlDocument` (from the older API).

This shouldn't be a problem though, as basically you just need to select an element and create an `XmlReader` from it. It looks like your code can just be changed to:

```
protected void BindUserDetails(string userName)
{
    UserService.ServiceSoapClient client = new UserService.ServiceSoapClient();
    XElement element = client.GetUserDetails(userName);
    if (element != null)
    {
        DataSet dsresult = new DataSet();
        XmlReader reader = element.CreateReader();
        dsresult.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
        gvUserDetails.DataSource = dsresult;
    }
    else
    {
        gvUserDetails.DataSource = null;
    }
    gvUserDetails.DataBind();
}
```

You could potentially refactor that further to extract the "convert `XElement` to `DataSet`" functionality:

```
// You could *consider* making this an extension method
public static DataSet ToDataSetOrNull(XElement source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    DataSet result = new DataSet();
    result.ReadXml(source.CreateReader(), XmlReadMode.Auto);
    return result;
}
```

Then your `BindUserDetails` code is just:

```
protected void BindUserDetails(string userName)
{
    UserService.ServiceSoapClient client = new UserService.ServiceSoapClient();
    gvUserDetails.DataSource = ToDataSetOrNull(client.GetUserDetails(userName));
    gvUserDetails.DataBind();
}
```

... and if you have other "BindXyzDetails" methods, they'll be similarly short.

Comment: ---i thank you for your time... the first solution has returned an error during execution " CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'" which was reverse of the issue i posted .

The 2nd solution returned "CS1502: The best overloaded method match for '_Default.ToDataSetOrNull(System.Xml.Linq.XElement)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @Phanindra: That doesn't like an execution error - that sounds like a compilation error. But the error doesn't make sense - if you hover over `GetUserDetails`, what return type does it show?

Comment: sorry my mistake its a compilation error .
i guess there is issue with my web method only.. i have updated my question as well ..

Comment: @Phanindra: Now that you've added the method, your original compilation error makes no sense :(